# Why do I get errors installing precompiled versions of LAPACK on Windows?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, matrix, lapack, precompiled, armadillo

I am trying to use the Armadillo matrix library to do matrix calculations and it needs BLAS and LAPACK. The Armadillo documentation recommended getting the precompiled versions from [http://www.stanford.edu/~vkl/code/libs.html](http://www.stanford.edu/%7Evkl/code/libs.html)

There are `.lib` and `.dll` files in there. The only problem is I don't know how to get Visual Studio (Express Edition 2008) to recognize these files. I try to copy them to the Visual C++ include and lib directories `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\lib\`, but it doesn't seem to do anything because when I try to compile my program, I get lots of "unresolved external symbol" errors that say it can't find LAPACK functions.

Here are the error messages:

```
1>Linking...
1>LINK : warning LNK4076: invalid incremental status file 'C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\TentPitcher\Debug\TentPitcher.ilk'; linking nonincrementally
1>   Creating library C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\TentPitcher\Debug\TentPitcher.lib and object C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\TentPitcher\Debug\TentPitcher.exp
1>Cell3DXT.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _zgetrf_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::lapack::getrf_<double>(int *,int *,double *,int *,int *,int *)" (??$getrf_@N@lapack@arma@@YAXPAH0PAN000@Z)
1>ThreeCell3DXT.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _zgetrf_
1>Cell3DXT.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cgetrf_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::lapack::getrf_<double>(int *,int *,double *,int *,int *,int *)" (??$getrf_@N@lapack@arma@@YAXPAH0PAN000@Z)
1>ThreeCell3DXT.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cgetrf_
1>Cell3DXT.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _dgetrf_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::lapack::getrf_<double>(int *,int *,double *,int *,int *,int *)" (??$getrf_@N@lapack@arma@@YAXPAH0PAN000@Z)
1>ThreeCell3DXT.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _dgetrf_
1>Cell3DXT.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _sgetrf_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::lapack::getrf_<double>(int *,int *,double *,int *,int *,int *)" (??$getrf_@N@lapack@arma@@YAXPAH0PAN000@Z)
1>ThreeCell3DXT.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _sgetrf_
1>Cell3DXT.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _zgemv_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::blas::gemv_<double>(char const *,int const *,int const *,double const *,double const *,int const *,double const *,int const *,double const *,double *,int const *)" (??$gemv_@N@blas@arma@@YAXPBDPBH1PBN21212PAN1@Z)
1>ThreeCell3DXT.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _zgemv_
1>TwoCell3DXT.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _zgemv_
1>Cell3DXT.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cgemv_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::blas::gemv_<double>(char const *,int const *,int const *,double const *,double const *,int const *,double const *,int const *,double const *,double *,int const *)" (??$gemv_@N@blas@arma@@YAXPBDPBH1PBN21212PAN1@Z)
1>ThreeCell3DXT.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cgemv_
1>TwoCell3DXT.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cgemv_
1>Cell3DXT.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _dgemv_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::blas::gemv_<double>(char const *,int const *,int const *,double const *,double const *,int const *,double const *,int const *,double const *,double *,int const *)" (??$gemv_@N@blas@arma@@YAXPBDPBH1PBN21212PAN1@Z)
1>ThreeCell3DXT.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _dgemv_
1>TwoCell3DXT.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _dgemv_
1>Cell3DXT.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _sgemv_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::blas::gemv_<double>(char const *,int const *,int const *,double const *,double const *,int const *,double const *,int const *,double const *,double *,int const *)" (??$gemv_@N@blas@arma@@YAXPBDPBH1PBN21212PAN1@Z)
1>ThreeCell3DXT.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _sgemv_
1>TwoCell3DXT.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _sgemv_
1>Cell3DXT.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _zgemm_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::blas::gemm_<double>(char const *,char const *,int const *,int const *,int const *,double const *,double const *,int const *,double const *,int const *,double const *,double *,int const *)" (??$gemm_@N@blas@arma@@YAXPBD0PBH11PBN21212PAN1@Z)
1>ThreeCell3DXT.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _zgemm_
1>TwoCell3DXT.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _zgemm_
1>Cell3DXT.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cgemm_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::blas::gemm_<double>(char const *,char const *,int const *,int const *,int const *,double const *,double const *,int const *,double const *,int const *,double const *,double *,int const *)" (??$gemm_@N@blas@arma@@YAXPBD0PBH11PBN21212PAN1@Z)
1>ThreeCell3DXT.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cgemm_
1>TwoCell3DXT.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cgemm_
1>Cell3DXT.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _dgemm_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::blas::gemm_<double>(char const *,char const *,int const *,int const *,int const *,double const *,double const *,int const *,double const *,int const *,double const *,double *,int const *)" (??$gemm_@N@blas@arma@@YAXPBD0PBH11PBN21212PAN1@Z)
1>ThreeCell3DXT.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _dgemm_
1>TwoCell3DXT.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _dgemm_
1>Cell3DXT.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _sgemm_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::blas::gemm_<double>(char const *,char const *,int const *,int const *,int const *,double const *,double const *,int const *,double const *,int const *,double const *,double *,int const *)" (??$gemm_@N@blas@arma@@YAXPBD0PBH11PBN21212PAN1@Z)
1>ThreeCell3DXT.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _sgemm_
1>TwoCell3DXT.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _sgemm_
1>Cell3DXT.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _zgetri_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::lapack::getri_<double>(int *,double *,int *,int *,double *,int *,int *)" (??$getri_@N@lapack@arma@@YAXPAHPAN00100@Z)
1>ThreeCell3DXT.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _zgetri_
1>Cell3DXT.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cgetri_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::lapack::getri_<double>(int *,double *,int *,int *,double *,int *,int *)" (??$getri_@N@lapack@arma@@YAXPAHPAN00100@Z)
1>ThreeCell3DXT.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cgetri_
1>Cell3DXT.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _dgetri_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::lapack::getri_<double>(int *,double *,int *,int *,double *,int *,int *)" (??$getri_@N@lapack@arma@@YAXPAHPAN00100@Z)
1>ThreeCell3DXT.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _dgetri_
1>Cell3DXT.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _sgetri_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::lapack::getri_<double>(int *,double *,int *,int *,double *,int *,int *)" (??$getri_@N@lapack@arma@@YAXPAHPAN00100@Z)
1>ThreeCell3DXT.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _sgetri_
1>TwoCell3DXT.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _dgesvd_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::lapack::gesvd_<double>(char *,char *,int *,int *,double *,int *,double *,double *,int *,double *,int *,double *,int *,int *)" (??$gesvd_@N@lapack@arma@@YAXPAD0PAH1PAN122121211@Z)
1>TwoCell3DXT.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _sgesvd_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::lapack::gesvd_<double>(char *,char *,int *,int *,double *,int *,double *,double *,int *,double *,int *,double *,int *,int *)" (??$gesvd_@N@lapack@arma@@YAXPAD0PAH1PAN122121211@Z)
1>C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\TentPitcher\Debug\TentPitcher.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 18 unresolved externals
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\TentPitcher\TentPitcher\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>TentPitcher - 43 error(s), 1 warning(s)
```

"`Cell3DXT`", "`TwoCell3DXT`", and "`ThreeCell3DXT`" are classes in my own code. Also in the LAPACK and BLAS files above, there are ".exp files" - what are those and do those have something to do with the problem?

Comment: Can't help you without seeing the error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the answer to my problem. The problem was that I knew I had to put the directory containing the LAPACK .lib file in the list of library directories (Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VC++ Directories -> Library Files) but forgot that I also had to add it to the "Additional Dependencies" under Project -> (Project Name) Properties -> Linker -> Input.

Comment: Could you please tell me, where did you find the the lapack.lib file, in armadillo directory. if you find them somwhere else can you please find the link to download for a 64 bit machine

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I solved it as follows:

1. download and extract the LAPACK (LIB+DLL) and BLASS (LIB+DLL)from victor's site,
2. Add the LAPACK and BLASS paths to linker search directories for example `Project->Build Options->Search Directories->Linker' in Code::Blocks,
3. Add lapack_win32.lib to Linker Settings,
4. Uncomment `#define ARMA_USE_LAPACK' in  [Armadillo PATH]/include/armadillo_bits/config.hpp