# LAPACK on Visual C/C++ 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, lapack, blas

I want to use LAPACK and BLAS in Visual C/C++ 2010 (add LAPACK and BLAS libs to Visual C/C++ 2010), so I was reading a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324362/installing-precompiled-versions-of-lapack-on-windows) (The same but with visual C/C++ 2008),He claims he solved it like:

> I figured out the answer to my
>   problem. The problem was that I knew I
>   had to put the directory containing
>   the LAPACK .lib file in the list of
>   library directories (Tools -> Options
>   -> Projects and Solutions -> VC++ Directories -> Library Files) but
>   forgot that I also had to add it to
>   the "Additional Dependencies" under
>   Project -> (Project Name) Properties
>   -> Linker -> Input.

When I tried to follow his solution, after getting **Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VC++ Directories Visual**, C/C++ 2010 says the VC++ directories is unused...

So now how do I add .libs so Visual C/C++ 2010 recognize them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add into Project settings: Linker -> Input.